# Is there any way to move recent redshift insert data to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Honestly speaking, requirement from business team , recently added data should move to s3..  and s3 have history of records. looked below options

1. Looked at Lambda and couldn't find any event trigger for redshift.
2. Kinesis Firehose - There is no source to configure redshift.

Please suggest the best way to move the data.

we added new column - is_processed - new data marked as '1' otherwise 0. From lambda , we filter based on is_processed =1 and selected data is moving to S3..But the problem is no EVENT trigger for Redshift.. we scheduled the job particular time and move the data to s3..

Note:
using Lambda (unload command) I moved redshift data to s3 (snapshot) based on datapipline.

Comment: Team.. have any solution on this

Comment: How do you term "recent Redshift data"? Is it in one table, or lots of tables? Do the rows that were inserted have a timestamp to identify "recent" data? _WHY_ do you wish to do this? If you can provide an explanation of your wider situation, we might be able to provide a suitable method or alternative. Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: updated my questions

Comment: You still did not address the questions I suggested in my comment above. Without that information, we cannot give a suitable answer. It is easy to move data from Redshift to S3 using the `UNLOAD` command. The hard part is whatever you mean by "recent data".

Comment: added more info